# How to show hide nvd3 pie chart labels programmatically

Tags: nvd3.js, pie-chart

I am stuck at a very small issue. I need to show and hide pie labels on click of radio button. I am using nvd3 pie chart with Dojo.
Following is the code snippet:

```
if(this._elemPool.data_type.widget[0].checked) {
          this.connectedWidgets.graph.chart.labelType("value");
          this.connectedWidgets.graph.chart.showLabels(false);
        } else {
          this.connectedWidgets.graph.chart.labelType("percent");
          this.connectedWidgets.graph.chart.showLabels(true);
        }
```

When I select percent labels option first it works correctly then when i select value option it does not hide the label nor does it show values.

Can anyone please help me resolve this. I need to show label only when it is percent otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like NVD3 forgets to remove labels. You could manually remove all elements in your chart as a workaround. Execute the following lines after you have made changes to your chart's settings:

```
d3.select("#chart svg").selectAll("*").remove();
chart.update();
```

### Demo

```js
var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.label
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.value
    });

  d3.select("#chart svg")
    .datum(exampleData())
    .transition().duration(350)
    .call(chart);

  return chart;
}, function() {
  switchToPercentageMode();
});

function switchToPercentageMode() {
  chart.labelType("percent")
    .showLabels(true);
  d3.select("#chart svg").selectAll("*").remove();
  chart.update();
}

function switchToValueMode() {
  chart.labelType("value")
    .showLabels(false);
  d3.select("#chart svg").selectAll("*").remove();
  chart.update();
}

$("#percentage").change(function() {
  switchToPercentageMode();
});

$("#value").change(function() {
  switchToValueMode();
});

function exampleData() {
  return [{
    "label": "One",
    "value": 29.765957771107
  }, {
    "label": "Two",
    "value": 0
  }, {
    "label": "Three",
    "value": 32.807804682612
  }, {
    "label": "Four",
    "value": 196.45946739256
  }, {
    "label": "Five",
    "value": 0.19434030906893
  }, {
    "label": "Six",
    "value": 98.079782601442
  }, {
    "label": "Seven",
    "value": 13.925743130903
  }, {
    "label": "Eight",
    "value": 5.1387322875705
  }];
}
```

```css
#chart {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="chartMode" value="percentage" id="percentage" checked>
<label for="percentage">Percentage</label>
<input type="radio" name="chartMode" value="value" id="value">
<label for="value">Value</label>

<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```